# Generic type constraints on an interface method

Tags: c#, .net, generics, interface

I'm doing the following in my interface, reason being I don't want to be tightly coupled to the implementation of IEquipment in my implementations of IEquipmentDataProvider

```
public interface IEquipmentDataProvider
{
  IEquipment GetEquipment<E>(string Path) where E : IEquipment, new();
}
```

But I think that the type constraints should be left to the implementation and I should just declare `IEquipment GetEquipment(string path);` in my interface. However, if I do that it's an interface for a redundant method as that method will never get called.

Is it considered okay to implement type constraints in an interface method, or is there another pattern I should consider?

Edit:
The reason I'm doing this is because I don't want my data access layer to have to use a concrete implementation of IEquipment and I can leave that to the domain logic layer. Hence the use of the generics , which will be an instance of IEquipment but decided upon by dll.  And called with

```
Equipment eq = da.GetEquipment<Equipment>("somepath"); // where eq is Iequipment, and da is IEquipmentDataProvider
```

Comment: Did you mean to write `E GetEquipment<E>(string Path)` so that `E` is used in the signature of the method?

Comment: No, I specifically wanted IEquipment

Comment: why dont you want to put type parameter to interface? `IEquipmentDataProvider<T> where T:IEquipment, new()`

Comment: There seems to be a contradiction in the design intent, if I may point it out to you, which being that one constraint is interface and the other an instantiation. You may want to rethink the design because a constraint as an interface by itself is pretty 'ah-hum' and coupling it with a constructor requirement is pretty much a bummer, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @tym32167 I guess I could do that also.

Comment: I don't get how this interface method can be used. So I have instance of `IEquipmentDataProvider`, only thing I can do is `GetEquipment<SomeSpecificEquipment>`, but how do I know which `SomeSpecificEquipment`?

Comment: Can you explain, how you want to use type parameter  `<E>`? Additionally, if you want to have different code for different types, it is better to have different implementations, like `IDataProvider<ClassA>`, `IDataProvider<ClassB>`, etc

Comment: Can you explain why `E GetEquipment<E>(string Path) where E : IEquipment, new();` isn't something you'd want to do?

Comment: @tym32167 I'm using `<E>` because I don't want my data access layer to have to aware of concrete instances of E, and leave that decision to domain logic. This, of course, may be the wrong approach.

Comment: @Enigmativity is it something I want to/not want to do in the interface is what I'm unsure of. I don't know if it's a poor design or not, hence my question.

Comment: @Phil - It's an excellent design if that's what you want to do. There's nothing wrong with it. It's what those constraints were designed to do.

Comment: @Enigmativity - thanks! :) I've update my post to try and illustrate this better.

Comment: @EnigmativityHow do you declare so magnanimously that it is an excellent design? :D Can you prove it with a test because declaring grandly that a design is excellent or has nothing wrong with it has no weightage without a test?

Comment: @user2347763 - Not so. My exact statement was "It's an excellent design if that's what you want to do." I was cagey.

Comment: @Enigmativity- There should be an emoticon for cagey expressions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I think that the type constraints should be left to the implementation and I should just declare IEquipment GetEquipment(string path); in my interface.

While I can see what you mean, I do think it's relevant here. Ignoring your type constraints, your interface definition makes it painfully clear that this is intended to work with **equipment**:

- `IEquipmentDataProvider`
- `GetEquipment()`
- Return type `IEquipment`

It's almost unavoidable that you'd want to limit the usable types to those that implement `IEquipment`.

Does the following make sense to you? Is this an intended use case?

```
public class StringProvider : IEquipmentDataProvider
{
    //...
}

var provider = new StringProvider();
var equipment = provider.GetEquipment<string>(myPath);
```

I'm pretty sure that it doesn't. Because it doesn't make sense to use anything other than an `IEquipment` implementation.

---

I think the issue is bigger than you're currently discussing. I see some other minor inconsistencies:

- You make a generic `E` type argument, yet your return value is of type `IEquipment`. Why? Why not make `E` the return type? Existing code such as `IEquipment myEquipment = myProvider.GetEquipment()` will still work without needing changes, and you have the optional benefit of returning a **specific** type should you ever need it.
- I don't quite understand why the method is generic but the class/interface itself isn't. There are use cases for generic methods, but yours seems to fit a generic class/interface much better.

I want to further address the second bullet point. Your interface, when implemented, will ensure that **every** implementation can get **every** type of `IEquipment.

Compare this to the generic class version:

```
public interface IEquipmentDataProvider<E> where E : IEquipment, new()
{
    E GetEquipment<E>(string Path);
}
```

Pretty much the same code. But now, you can implement these interfaces specifically or generically, **however you want it**:

```
public class HammerDataProvider : IEquipmentDataProvider<Hammer> {}

public class SawDataProvider : IEquipmentDataProvider<Saw> {}

public class AllEquipmentDataProvider : IEquipmentDataProvider<IEquipment> {}
```

Every implementation of `IEquipmentDataProvider` can choose to either limit itself to a specific type (`Hammer`, `Saw`), or it can handle every implementation of `IEquipment`.

**Edit**
This also allows you to combine multiple interfaces, which can be implemented separately in the same class:

```
public class HammerAndSawDataProvider : IEquipmentDataProvider<Hammer>, IEquipmentDataProvider<Saw> {}
```

*Due to a lack of type distinction between the two interface methods, you'll need to rely on [**explicit** interface implementation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/136319/whats-the-difference-between-implementing-an-interface-explicitly-or-implicitly). Maybe not what you want.*
*If your interface method had had different signatures between different generic types (e.g.* `GetEquipment<E>(E myEquipment)` *), then you could've avoided needing to use explicit interface implementation.*

This may be one step too far for your requirements, but it does showcase that you get absolute control over *which* equipment can be handled by a specific provider.

---

**To summarize**

- The type constraint seems to be a given, based on the naming that you've used for the class and method.
- It would make little to no sense to ever use a type that deviates from the suggested type constraint.
- If you're already using a generic type; you're better off having your return type be the generic type. At worst, it doesn't break anything. At best, it allows for better type safety and less hard casting (e.g. it removes the need for performing a cast in `Hammer myHammer = (Hammer)provider.GetEquipment(myPath);`).
- More often than not, you'll want to use the generic parameter at the class/interface level. The main drawback of generic methods (without a generic class) is that you have to repeatedly define a type constraint for every submethod that is called in the toplevel method. Generic methods (without a generic class) are generally only really warranted in "toolkit" methods, as far as I can think of right now.
- **Pedantic**: I would rename the generic parameter to `TEquipment` (or `TE` if you want to be terse). Type parameters are usually named in a way that e.g. `TElement` is read as "type of the Element". But this is a matter of style and naming convention.

  - In your code, you do adhere to the "interface names begin with I" convention. Generic types have a similar convention about beginning with T.

---

**Response to OP's update**

> Edit: The reason I'm doing this is because I don't want my data access layer to have to use a concrete implementation of IEquipment and I can leave that to the domain logic layer. Hence the use of the generics , which will be an instance of IEquipment but decided upon by dll.

This somewhat reaffirms my assertion that you should use a generic class/interface, not just a generic method.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If one were to paraphrase this line of code,

```
IEquipment GetEquipment<E>(string Path) where E : IEquipment, new();
```

it would become "**a `GetEquipment` generic method with a constraint of type `IEquipment` with an implementation that has a default constructor"**.

Instead, the design could simply be an explicit interface method

```
Equipment eInstance=new Equipment();

IEquipmentDataProvider iEInstance=(IEquipmentIEquipmentDataProvider )eInstance;

iEInstance=iEInstance.GetEquipment(path);
```

so that, even if you have another class implementing the `GetEquipment` method differently, you could simply call the right `GetEquipment` method of `IEquipment` by using the explicit interface method.

**Edit: after the OP's edit**

```
EquipmentDataProvider edp=new EquipmentDataProvider();

IEquipmentDataProvider da=(IEquipmentDataProvider)edp; // An explicit method invocation to ensure that the EquipmentataProvider's GetEquipment and not some other Equipment class' GetEquipment is called. This is what is the intent of the

Equipment eq = da.GetEquipment<Equipment>("somepath");
```

Comment: (1) It is massively unlikely that `Equipment` is supposed to implement the `IEquipmentDataProvider` interface; which is what you seem to have assumed here. (2) Your code makes no sense; the second line is redundant since it gets overwritten by the third line (which, in turn, does not rely on the second line at all).

Comment: I didn't notice I had typed IEquipment and not IEquipmentDataProvider. Anyway, if a class does not implement an interface, what is the purpose of the interface?

Comment: I didn't say that **nothing** implements the interface. I'm pretty sure OP has more than one class in their application. Just because he didn't list them all does not mean they don't exist. `IEquipment` is implemented by the **entity** classes, whereas `IEquipmentIEquipmentDataProvider` is obviously intended to be implemented by the **data access** classes (which retrieve `IEquipment` objects, i.e. the entities).

Comment: The edited answer, while better, is answering a different question than is posted here. OP is not asking for explicit/implicit interface methods. He's asking on which level he should place his generic type constraints. You haven't adequately explained why explicit interface methods are a valid solution (or alternate approach) to OP's actual problem.

Comment: @Flater Not really, the OP clearly says that the concern is design so my answer suggested a supplement. The usage of     IEquipment GetEquipment<E>(string Path) where E : IEquipment, new(); is overloaded in intent, I have just simplified the intent with an alternate and possibly, the correct, way, of achieving what the original code intends to do in a rather roundabout way.

Comment: (1) There is no overloading happening here. At no point has OP been talking about ensuring that the interface method is separated from a similarly named but unrelated method in the implementing class. (2) Interfaces do not interfere with overloaded methods that are unrelated to the interface. An interface only cares that _its_ methods are implemented by the class. An interface does not care at all about any additional methods the class might additionally contain. That includes overloaded methods, which will never be available through the interface if the interface does not contain them.

Comment: I don't think you are reading correctly. You have simply picked the word "Overloading" to go off into a tangent that it is about function overloading (my statement is pretty clear that the line of code is overloaded in intent (not method)).